# Inventory Management System PHPGrid

Tags: php, wamp, phpgrid

I'm trying to replicate this demo of `phpGrid` using `wamp`.

My current PHP's version is `5.6.31`.

When I try to view the `Products.php` page it says Fatal error:

> Class 'phpGrid\C_DataGrid' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\inventory-manager-master\inventory-manager-master\products.php
>   on line 16

Could it be that my php version is lower?

Should I upgrade to Php7 or what's the best solution?

Thanks in advance.

Go easy on me as I am a noob.

The code is as follows.

```
<?php
use phpGrid\C_DataGrid;

include_once("phpGrid/conf.php");
include_once('inc/head.php');
?>

<h1>My Inventory Manager</h1>

<?php
$_GET['currentPage'] = 'products';
include_once('inc/menu.php');
?>

<?php
$dgProd = new C_DataGrid('SELECT * FROM products', 'id', 'products');
$dgProd->set_col_hidden('id', false);
$dgProd->enable_autowidth(true)->set_dimension('auto', '200px')-
>set_pagesize(100);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Some code would be nice, preferably from the file that throws the error.

Comment: Does PHPGrid say it will run on PHP5.6.31?

Comment: I'm sorry the code is as follows. It's the original code of PHPGrid demo. I've changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

The free phpGrid Lite does not require the namespace

```
use phpGrid\C_DataGrid;
```

In fact, it will throw an error if you try.